# setting jsonSerialization maxJsonLength in ASP.net Web.Config gives 500 error

Tags: jquery, ajax, web-config, webmethod

So, I keep getting the 500 - Internal server error page on my .net site when I set the `maxJsonLength` in my `web.config`.

I'm modifying the `.config` because even though I use `MaxJsonLength = Int32.MaxValue` on my vb.net `JavaScriptSerializer`, I'm still getting `InvalidOperationException` for a large dictionary I'm trying to transmit even though it's well below the `4GB` the `MaxJsonLength @ Int32.MaxValue` allows or even the supposed `4mb` default limit.

I'm using `toolkitscriptmanager` if that means anything.

```xml
<system.web.extensions>
    <scripting>
        <webServices>
            <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="2147483647" />
        </webServices>
    </scripting>
</system.web.extensions>
```

this didn't help (actually, it also gives 500 error without above code)

```xml
<sectionGroup name="system.web.extensions" type="System.Web.Extensions">
    <sectionGroup name="scripting" type="System.Web.Extensions">
        <sectionGroup name="webServices" type="System.Web.Extensions">
            <section name="jsonSerialization" type="System.Web.Extensions" />
        </sectionGroup>
    </sectionGroup>
</sectionGroup>
```

heard this should help with `InvalidOperationException`, but it didn't.  I took it out, and still 500 error.

```xml
<add key="aspnet:MaxJsonDeserializerMembers" value="2147483647" />
```

Many thanks in advance!

**Edit**

Same problem, but his solution doesn't work for me.  The last code he added also gives 500 error.  [Problem with <system.web.extensions> config group when upgrading to .NET 4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3209192/problem-with-system-web-extensions-config-group-when-upgrading-to-net-4-0)

Comment: if you inspect it firebug of chrome do you get an error message in the response with the 500 ?  what makes you think the error is caused by the size of the response , there are many other reasons for 500 error

Comment: Thank-you for replying.  It gives no details in the response header, and the response is just the typical .net 500 error page.  The error shows up when I put the jsonSerialization maxJsonLength line in.  If I take it out, everything's fine except I can't get super huge JSON's which I need.

Comment: weird, I use  <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="50000000"/> in my code all the time in web.config just like you did with no problem ,  is it in <configuration>   ?

Comment: indeed.  just trying to add the configsections causes 500 too.  i'm trying all the solutions in that link in my edit

Comment: take the line out of the other code MaxJsonLength = Int32.MaxValue

Comment: will try, but it's 500ing for everything

Comment: try running on localhost and debugging for specific errors , when running on server you won't be able to get specific errors

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem for me was that I put the code in the beginning of the web.config.  For some reason, putting it at the end worked.

Not an expert, so I have no idea why that worked.

It worked without the last two code sections that I tried to make it work.

Answer (score 4):

I agreed with Gracchus, I put this below block in end of web.config file

```
<system.web.extensions>
    <scripting>
        <webServices>
            <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="2147483647"/>
        </webServices>
    </scripting>
</system.web.extensions>`
```

Comment: Make sure .ajax() call sync:true (duplicate attempts to call may end up your request)

Comment: You mean at the end of the `configuration`node?

Answer (score 2):

As none of above worked for me so I used this-

```
JsonResult result = Json(<your result>, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
result.MaxJsonLength = int.MaxValue;
return result;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<system.web.extensions>
    <scripting>
      <webServices>
        <!--<jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="50000000">
        </jsonSerialization>-->
        <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="500000000">
          <!--50000000-->
        </jsonSerialization>
      </webServices>
    </scripting>
  </system.web.extensions>
```

Above settings worked for me. Additionally i had to set the target framework of the website to .Net 4.0. This web config setting was giving me **500 error** when the target framework was set to .Net 2.0

To change the framework, goto IIS and select **Application Pool** Right click on your website name and select **Advanced settings**. Here you can change the .Net Framework Version by clicking on the drop-down.

Also i had this setting at the bottom of the web config. Only for good luck :)

Hope this helps.