# How to increase the json size limit for ASP.NET WebAPI Post call?

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-web-api, json.net

My form on the page is a little too large. It collects the monthly measurement data. Please take a look at the sample:

```
{
"Year":2013,
"Month":3,
"Records":[
    {"Id":0,"Date":"3/1/2013","RiverSection":5,"UserNumber":56},
    {"Id":0,"Date":"3/1/2013","RiverSection":7,"UserNumber":200},
    {"Id":0,"Date":"3/1/2013","RiverSection":8,"UserNumber":556},
    {"Id":0,"Date":"3/2/2013","RiverSection":5,"UserNumber":56},
    {"Id":0,"Date":"3/2/2013","RiverSection":7,"UserNumber":200},
    ...
    ...
    {"Id":0,"Date":"3/31/2013","RiverSection":7,"UserNumber":200}
}
```

So I am posting the big data to an APIController.

I works fine in my local machine using the Visual Studio debugger server. But after I uploaded the code to the server (IIS 6). It gives a `500 Internal Server Error`.

I tried posting some sample data and checked the length of the stringified json.

In one sample data set, the length of my json is 5743, and I got a "success". But if the json size goes up to 17345, I got a `500 Internal Server Error`.

So I tried to increase the limit of json. Base on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1151987/can-i-set-an-unlimited-length-for-maxjsonlength-in-web-config/12278956#12278956)

In `Web.Config`:

```
<system.web.extensions>
<scripting>
  <webServices>
    <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="5000000">
    </jsonSerialization>
  </webServices>
</scripting>
</system.web.extensions>
```

But it is not working.

There is another answer, using:

```
var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
serializer.MaxJsonLength = Int32.MaxValue;
```

But where should we place this code? in `Global.asax`?

Please note I am using an IIS 6. So is it a problem? How can I correctly increase the limit of json size so that my data can hit the WebApi action?

Thank you for any assistance.

Comment: This helped me about the same problem:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/16436700/1740883

Comment: This [link][1] might help in solving the problem. Faced similar issue.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12750689/setting-jsonserialization-maxjsonlength-in-asp-net-web-config-gives-500-error/

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try adding the `aspnet:MaxJsonDeserializerMembers` under `appSettings` in `web.config`

```
<add key="aspnet:MaxJsonDeserializerMembers" value="20000"/>
```

Source: 
[An ASP.NET request that has lots of form keys, files, or JSON payload members fails with an exception](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2661403)