# why can't asp.net find the appropriate apicontroller when input is large?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I have a function that saves a list of my entities at once.

```
public void Save(IEnumerable<SubjectData> subjectDatas)
{
    var request = _requestFactory.CreateRequest("api/subjectData", Method.POST, AccessToken.AccessToken, new List<SubjectData>(subjectDatas));
    var response = Client.Execute(request);
    _responseDeserializer.Deserialize<SubjectData>(response);
}
```

That's calling a wep API function:

```
// POST api/<controller>
public void Post([FromBody]List<SubjectData> values)
{
   _subjectDataService.Save(values, User.Identity.Name);
}
```

when I `subjectDatas` is a list of about 30, this works fine. However, when `subjectDatas` is very large (in my test case, over 96000), I get an unexpected error. The response has StatusCode NotFound. what's going on? Why can it suddenly not find the right controller?

Answer (score 0):

According to these answers

[Is there a limit on how much JSON can hold?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1262396/5233410)

[How to increase the json size limit for ASP.NET WebAPI Post call?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18262484/5233410)

Quoting some sources

[An ASP.NET request that has lots of form keys, files, or JSON payload members fails with an exception](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2661403)

[JavaScriptSerializer.MaxJsonLength Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.maxjsonlength.aspx)

There appears to be a default max size of data that can be parse by ASP.Net and in order to increase it you have to make some changes to `web.config`

This was one of the suggestions offered:

> Try adding the `aspnet:MaxJsonDeserializerMembers` under `appSettings` in `web.config`

```
<add key="aspnet:MaxJsonDeserializerMembers" value="20000"/>
```

Another Quoted source:

> Applications that hit this limit for JSON payloads can modify the
>   ASP.NET appSetting `aspnet:MaxJsonDeserializerMembers`, as shown below
>   in an ASP.NET application’s configuration file. This setting addresses
>   error message 3 from the "Symptoms" section.

```
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="aspnet:MaxJsonDeserializerMembers" value="1000" />
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

> **Note** Increasing this value above the default setting increases the susceptibility of your server to the Denial of Service vulnerability
>   that is discussed in security bulletin MS11-100.

Answer (score 0):

According to  [Max Parameter length in MVC](http://forums.asp.net/t/1842984.aspx?Max%20Parameter%20length%20in%20MVC)
this is a windows restriction. in your url, the parameter is part of the path. windows restricts a path segments length.

you should change `UrlSegmentMaxLength` in regedit.

create a `DWORD` value in the following registery key

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\HTTP\Parameters`

`UrlSegmentMaxCount`

> Maximum number of URL path segments. If zero, the count bounded by the
>   maximum value of a ULONG.
>
> Valid value range 0 - 16,383

[Http.sys registry settings for Windows](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/820129)